# How to connect a testcontainer to an existing docker network using testcontainers-node?

Tags: node.js, testcontainers

I'm using [testcontainers-node](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-node) library. In my setup, I'm creating a docker container using docker-compose (outside of testcontainers setup code) with a custom defined `bridge` network and then I spin-up testcontainers using the aforementioned library. I want my testcontainers to join the network I created earlier using network name. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using

```
.withNetworkMode(<name_of_the_network>)
```

Assuming your network is called `docker_dev_integration_network`:

```
mockContainer.container = await new ConfigurableGenericContainer('gcr.io/gke-utility/mocks')
        .withExposedPorts(mocksPort)
        .withStartupTimeout(startupTimeout)
        .withCommand([mockContainer.yaml])
        .withNetworkMode("docker_dev_integration_network")
        .start()
```

In your docker-compose you will have something like that:

```
services:
  serviceA:
    ...
    networks:
      - dev_integration_network
networks:
  dev_integration_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Keep in mind, that docker-compose appends to the network name the name of the folder where docker-compose.yml is located (in my case `.docker`)